# How to define an XML Schema for recursive and unknown-named elements?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

Is it possible to define an XML Schema for recursive, unknown-named elements?
For example:

```
<Bob age="72">
    <FavoriteColor>"Blue"</FavoriteColor>
    <Children>
        <Sally age="36">
            <FavoriteColor>"Green"</FavoriteColor>
            <Children />
        </Sally>
        <Joe age="34">
            <FavoriteColor>"Red"</FavoriteColor>
            <Children>
                <Tina age="5">
                    <FavoriteColor>"Blue"</FavoriteColor>
                    <Children />
                </Tina>
                <Frank age="6">
                    <FavoriteColor>"Yellow"</FavoriteColor>
                    <Children />
                </Frank>
            </Children>
        </Joe>
    </Children>
</Bob>
```

I'm fairly new to XSD, but I think this requires some combination of recursion and `<xs:any>`.

See:
[Recursion in an XML schema?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148988/recursion-in-an-xml-schema) and 
[how can I define an xsd file that allows unknown (wildcard) elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/943659/how-can-i-define-an-xsd-file-that-allows-unknown-wildcard-elements)

However I can't find a solution that doesn't involve rewriting my implied `Person` elements with the stricter form:

```
<Person name="Bob" age="72">
    <FavoriteColor />
    <Children />
```

Is the original XML Schema-able?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've correctly identified `xsd:any` as the solution to allowing any element under `Children`, and you've correctly identified the recursive type pattern for representing family-tree-like structures.

However, `xsd:any` is not up to the task of partial constraint of the elements it governs.  Once you use `xsd:any`, you lose control over markup beneath that point.  Its only options pertain to how validity is affected by the existence of definitions for encountered elements; see [processContents strict vs lax vs skip for xsd:any](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27420156/290085).

Trying to make the first example work will be an uphill battle.  (You could use assertions in XSD 1.1, but you'll be unnaturally forcing assertions to do what is intended to be done via simple content models.)  Go with the second form; it's better XML design.

Comment: The generic form also has the advantage of allowing `<Person name="Mary Ann"/>` You don't really want to constrain people to name their children according to the rules for NCNames.

Comment: Didn't mention that advantage because I figured that as long as parser writers' jobs are easier, the parents of Mary-Ann, Mary_Ann, or MaryAnn wouldn't mind.  :-)